# Calculate cost of order based on selections in PHP

Tags: php

I need to edit the pizza.php file so that it calculates the cost of the order after clicking submit based off the selections. The html and css is added in order to let you run the code as I have it. Any solutions for the PHP file would be much appreciated.

Cost are as follows:

Size: large: $9.95, x-large: $12.95

Toppings: pepperoni $1.25, mushrooms $1.25

### Crust: thin $0.00, original $0.00, deepdish $2.00

pizza.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$size=$_POST['size'];

$pepperoni=$_POST['pepperoni'];

$mushrooms=$_POST['mushrooms'];

$crust=$_POST['crust'];

$name=$_POST['name'];

$largeprice = 9.95;

$xlargeprice = 12.95;

$toppingsprice = 1.25;

if($crust == "Deepdish"){

$crustprice = 2.0;

}

else{

$crustprice = 0;

}



$file=fopen("pizza.txt", "a");

fwrite($file, $size);

fwrite($file, $pepperoni);

fwrite($file, $mushrooms);

fwrite($file, $crust);

fwrite($file, $name);

fclose($file);

echo"<h1>Pizza ordered, thank you $name!</h1>";

echo"<h1>Your total is </h1>";

}

?>
```

---

pizza.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Pizza</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pizza.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<h1>Pizzazz Pizza</h1>

<br>

<form action="pizza.php" method="post">

<div class="formclass">

<div class="left">

<label for="">Size</label><br>

<input type="radio" value='Large' name="size">Large<br>

<input type="radio" value='X-Large' name="size">X-Large

</div>

<div class="middle">

<label for="">Toppings</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni" name="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>

<input type="checkbox" value="Mushroom" name='mushrooms'>Mushrooms

</div>

<div class="right">

<label for="">Crust</label><br>

<select name="crust" id="">

<option value="">Select Crust</option>

<option value="Thin">Thin</option>

<option value="Original">Original</option>

<option value="Deepdish">Deep Dish</option>

</select><br>

</div>

</div>

<label for="">Name </label><input type="text" name="name">

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

pizza.css

```
.container {

border: 5px black solid;

width: 600px;

height: 200px;

margin: auto;

padding: 25px;

background-color: rgb(218, 153, 56);

}

.container h1 {

text-align: center;

line-height: 0px;

}

.container input {

margin: 10px;

}

.left {

width: 40%;

height: 100px;

}

.middle {

width: 30%;

height: 100px;

}

.right {

width: 30%;

height: 100px;

}

.formclass {

display: flex;

}
```

Comment: Create a `$total` variable you add the cost to depending on their selections? What have you tried? Btw, are you writing your code like that, completely without indentions and with unnecessary empty lines after each row? It make the code hard to read and follow. Good to know is that only checkboxes that are checked will be submitted with the form, so you should check if they exist in the `$_POST` array before trying to read them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I went a little ott here, but it works! (PHP8)

pizza.php

```
<?php

class Pizza {
    const FILE = 'pizza.txt';

    const SIZES = array(
        0 => 'Large',
        1 => 'X-Large',
    );

    const TOPPINGS = array (
        0 => 'Pepperoni',
        1 => 'Mushroom',
    );

    const CRUSTS = array (
        0 => 'Thin',
        1 => 'Original',
        2 => 'DeepDish',
    );

    const PRICE_TOPPINGS = 1.25;
    const PRICE_SIZE = array (
        0 => 9.95,
        1 => 12.95
    );
    Const PRICE_CRUST = array (
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 2,
    );

    private ?string $customerName = null;

    private array $chosenToppings = array();

    private ?int $size = 0;

    private ?int $crust = 0;

    public function saveToFile(): Pizza
    {
        $file = fopen(Pizza::FILE, "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($file, "Size:" . Pizza::SIZES[$this->getSize()]);
        foreach ($this->getChosenToppings() as $topping) {
            fwrite($file, "\nTopping:" . Pizza::TOPPINGS[$topping]);
        }
        fwrite($file, "\nCrust:" . Pizza::CRUSTS[$this->getCrust()]);
        fwrite($file, "\nName:" . $this->getCustomerName());
        fwrite($file, "\nPrice £:" . $this->calculatePizza());
        fwrite($file, "\n--------------------------------------\n");
        fclose($file);

        return $this;
    }

    public function calculatePizza(): float
    {
        $cost = array();
        $cost['crust'] = Pizza::PRICE_CRUST[$this->getCrust()];
        $cost['size'] = Pizza::PRICE_SIZE[$this->getSize()];
        $cost['toppings'] = count($this->getChosenToppings()) * Pizza::PRICE_TOPPINGS;

        return number_format((float) array_sum($cost), 2);
    }

    private function getFormattedLabel(string $label): string
    {
        return str_replace(' ', '', $label);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $customerName
     * @return Pizza
     */
    public function setCustomerName(?string $customerName): Pizza
    {
        $this->customerName = $customerName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChosenToppings(): array
    {
        return $this->chosenToppings;
    }

    public function addChosenTopping(int|string $topping): Pizza
    {
        if (is_string($topping) && in_array($topping, Pizza::TOPPINGS)) {
            $fToppings = array_flip(Pizza::TOPPINGS);
            $topping = $fToppings[$topping];
        }

        if (is_int($topping) && array_key_exists($topping, Pizza::TOPPINGS)) {
            $this->chosenToppings[] = $topping;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addChosenToppings(array $toppings): Pizza
    {
        foreach ($toppings as $topping) {
            if (is_null($topping)) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->addChosenTopping($topping);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $chosenToppings
     * @return Pizza
     */
    public function setChosenToppings(array $chosenToppings): Pizza
    {
        $this->chosenToppings = $chosenToppings;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|int|null $size
     * @return Pizza
     */
    public function setSize(null|string|int $size): Pizza
    {
        if ( ! is_int($size) && in_array($size, Pizza::SIZES)) {
            $fSize = array_flip(Pizza::SIZES);
            $size = $fSize[$size];
        } else {
            $size = 0;
        }

        $this->size = $size;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getCrust(): ?int
    {
        return $this->crust;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|int $crust
     * @return Pizza
     */
    public function setCrust(string|int $crust): Pizza
    {
        if ( ! is_numeric($crust)) {
            if (in_array($this->getFormattedLabel($crust), Pizza::CRUSTS)) {
                $fCrust = array_flip(Pizza::CRUSTS);
                $crust = $fCrust[$this->getFormattedLabel($crust)];
            } else {
                $crust = 0;
            }
        }

        $this->crust = $crust;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getThankYou(bool $echo = true): string
    {
        $output = <<<OUTPUT
        <h1>Pizza ordered, thank you {$this->getCustomerName()}!</h1>
        <h1>Your total is {$this->calculatePizza()}</h1>
        OUTPUT;

        if (true === $echo) {
            echo $output;
        }

        return $output;
    }
}

if (
    array_key_exists('submit', $_POST) &&
    ! empty($_POST['submit'])
) {
    $pizza = new Pizza;
    $pizza
        ->setSize($_POST['size'] ?? Pizza::SIZES[0])
        ->addChosenToppings(
            array (
                $_POST['pepperoni'] ?? null,
                $_POST['mushrooms'] ?? null,
            )
        )
        ->setCrust($_POST['crust'] ?? Pizza::CRUSTS[0])
        ->setCustomerName($_POST['name'] ?? 'Unknown')
        ->saveToFile()
        ->getThankYou()
    ;
}
include_once 'pizza.html';
```

pizza.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pizza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pizza.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Pizzazz Pizza</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="pizza.php" method="post">
        <div class="formclass">
            <div class="left">
                <label for="">Size</label><br>
                <input type="radio" value='Large' name="size">Large<br>
                <input type="radio" value='X-Large' name="size">X-Large
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <label for="">Toppings</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni" name="pepperoni">Pepperoni<br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Mushroom" name='mushrooms'>Mushrooms
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <label for="">Crust</label><br>
                <select name="crust" id="">
                    <option value="">Select Crust</option>
                    <option value="Thin">Thin</option>
                    <option value="Original">Original</option>
                    <option value="DeepDish">Deep Dish</option>
                </select><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label for="">Name </label><input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```